# Normalise orientation between 0 and 360

Tags: c#, rotation, angle

I'm working on a simple rotate routine which normalizes an objects rotation between 0 and 360 degrees. My C# code seems to be working but I'm not entirely happy with it. Can anyone improve on the code below making it a bit more robust?

```
public void Rotate(int degrees)
    {
        this.orientation += degrees;

        if (this.orientation < 0)
        {
            while (this.orientation < 0)
            {
                this.orientation += 360;
            }
        }
        else if (this.orientation >= 360)
        {
            while (this.orientation >= 360)
            {
                this.orientation -= 360;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just for anybody else who stumbles upon these magic solutions. I have tested several of these for true 0-360 values out. Using a gyro that can give values in the +/- many thousands range enzuguri's solution achieves this !! Saad Ahmed and QBziZ's solution yield -10 for an input of -10; not the 350 I would expect.
Hope this is helpful
JC

Comment: The `if`s can go for starters.

Answer (score 64):

Use modulo arithmetic:

```
this.orientation += degrees;

this.orientation = this.orientation % 360;

if (this.orientation < 0)
{
    this.orientation += 360;
}
```

Comment: Can you get a negative result from modulous? Floating point issue?

Comment: C gives you negatives, I'm assuming C# does the same. And, since degrees is an int, you're limited to integer rotations. It's not explicitly spelled out that orientation is an int but it would be strange if it wasn't.

Comment: Oh. So you can. -1 % 360 is negative 1. I expected 359. Silly me. You learn something every day.

Comment: (angle+3600) %360 (it allows 10 whole negative revolutions as input)

Answer (score 48):

This is one that normalizes to any range.
Useful for normalizing between [-180,180], [0,180] or [0,360].

( it's in C++ though )

```cpp
// Normalizes any number to an arbitrary range 
// by assuming the range wraps around when going below min or above max 
double normalize( const double value, const double start, const double end ) 
{
  const double width       = end - start   ;   // 
  const double offsetValue = value - start ;   // value relative to 0

  return ( offsetValue - ( floor( offsetValue / width ) * width ) ) + start ;
  // + start to reset back to start of original range
}
```

For ints

```cpp
// Normalizes any number to an arbitrary range 
// by assuming the range wraps around when going below min or above max 
int normalize( const int value, const int start, const int end ) 
{
  const int width       = end - start   ;   // 
  const int offsetValue = value - start ;   // value relative to 0

  return ( offsetValue - ( ( offsetValue / width ) * width ) ) + start ;
  // + start to reset back to start of original range
}
```

So basically the same but without the floor.
The version I personally use is a generic one that works for all numeric types and it also uses a redefined floor that does nothing in case of integral types.

Comment: This function is amazing, solved the "normalize angle problem" once and for all! :) leads to, if you just want to normalize in [0; 2*PI[ an angle:    angle -= Math.Floor(angle/(2*Math.PI))*2*Math.PI;

Comment: The function with the doubles is not handling very small figures well. For instance enter  normalise( -1.0E-15, 0.0, 360.0), the outcome will be 360.0. the outcome should be smaller than 360 imo.

Comment: What you say is true but very trivial. You should not confuse floating point arithmetic with actual analytical mathematics. Floating point on the most basic level is : here’s a finite bunch of numbers, with them, you have to try to get to the analytical solution with the least amount of error. In a bit more detail, floating point numbers are rational numbers with a finite set of numerators and denominators. It all depends on your application domain because no function will ever be perfect for the real world. In my case, such small numbers can be considered as such if the range is that big.

Answer (score 22):

This can be simplified to the following.

```cs
public void Rotate (int degrees) {
    this.orientation = (this.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    if (this.orientation < 0) this.orientation += 360;
}
```

C# follows the same rules as C and C++ and `angle % 360` will give you a value between `-359` and `359` for any integer. Then the second line is to ensure it's in the range `0` through `359` inclusive.

If you wanted to be "clever", you could get it down to one line:

```cs
this.orientation = (this.orientation + (degrees % 360) + 360) % 360;
```

This would keep it positive under all conditions but that's a nasty hack for saving one line of code, so I wouldn't do it, but I *will* explain it.

From `degrees % 360` you will get a number between `-359` and `359`. Adding `360` will modify the range to between `1` and `719`. If `orientation` is already positive, adding this will guarantee it still is, and the final `% 360` will bring it back to the range `0` through `359`.

At a bare *minimum*, you could simplify your code since the `if`s and `while`s can be combined. For example, the result of the conditions in these two lines is *always* the same, hence you don't need the surrounding `if`:

```cs
if (this.orientation < 0) {
   while (this.orientation < 0) {
```

So, to that end, you *could* do:

```cs
public void Rotate (int degrees) {
    this.orientation += degrees;
    while (this.orientation <   0) this.orientation += 360;
    while (this.orientation > 359) this.orientation -= 360;
}
```

but I'd *still* go for the modulus version since it avoids potentially expensive loops.

This will be important when a user enters 360,000,000,000 for the rotation (and they *will* do this, believe me) and then find they have to take an early lunch while your code grinds away :-)

Comment: I´d say `this.orientation = (this.orientation + degrees + 360) % 360;` is easier to read.

Comment: @jensgram, the problem with that one is that it can *still* give you a number in the range -359 through -1 if, for example, orientation is 0 and degrees is -719, giving -359. You have to normalize degrees first then force it to positive.

Comment: @paxdiablo, you're right! I didn't anticipate `degrees` to be outside +/-359.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer to avoid loops, conditionals, arbitrary offsets (3600), and `Math.____()` calls:

```
var degrees = -123;
degrees = (degrees % 360 + 360) % 360;
// degrees: 237
```

Comment: Oops, just saw @paxdiablo answer that mentioned this one-liner.

Comment: This is also great for shaders, where conditionals are very expensive.

Comment: why the double modulo? `-123 % 360 = 237`

Answer (score 11):

I sort of quickly mocked this up in AS3, but should work (you may need `+=` on the angle)

```
private Number clampAngle(Number angle)
{
    return (angle % 360) + (angle < 0 ? 360 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

formula for re-orienting circular values i.e to keep angle between 0 and 359 is:

```
angle + Math.ceil( -angle / 360 ) * 360
```

generalized formula for shifting angle orientation can be:

```
angle + Math.ceil( (-angle+shift) / 360 ) * 360
```

in which value of shift represent circular shift for e.g I want values in -179 to 180 then it can be represented as:
    angle + Math.ceil( (-angle-179) / 360 ) * 360

Comment: This is the simplest answer that works on fractions and negative numbers. Works also with arbitrary large numbers without loops.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but it would seem many of the preferred solutions make an assumption that a negative angle will not be lower than -360°. This solution makes no such assumption, works for virtually any angle that an int can represent, and does not do excessive multiplication or division:

```
public void Rotate(int degrees)
{
    this.orientation += degrees;
    
    if (this.orientation >= 0)
        this.orientation %= 360;
    else
        this.orientation = 360 - (360 - this.orientation) % 360;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making separate function for normalizing angle - it's a cleaner solution.

```
public static float NormalizeEulerAngle(float angle){
    var normalized = angle % 360;
    if(normalized < 0)
        normalized += 360;
    return normalized;
}
```

Fiddle proving that such function works as intended: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vh4CUa

And then you can use it like here:

```
public void Rotate(int degrees){
    orientation = NormalizeEulerAngle(orientation + degrees);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you guy's riddled with logic... not good for GPU ops.

*Here's a **purely mathematical** approach.*

First, the distilled expression--  This, the meat.

```
(  (angle % 360)  +  360  )   %   360
```

To re-use it, wrap it in a code-aritto like this:

```
var normee = (angle)=>{  return(   (  (angle % 360)  +  360  )   %   360   );  }
```

If you find this video useful or informative, please Like and Subscribe.

However, if you want to swim a little deeper, read on.

I saw you guy's answer's and was thinking about that Modulus... had to be a way with only a mathematical expression-- No logical operations.  No loops.  No recursive nesting.  Low expense.

I gave up for a sec 'cause my own use case actually works better with -180 to +180 limits before flipping the score, and I already had that figured out with just the math.

But I really wanted to know.  The 360 case.

Then it dawned on me.  What is the Modulus of 360, of the Modulus of the Coterminal Angle and 360?  Would that be Normalized?  Nope.  Playing in Node.JS terminal.

Test failed.  But it seemed close... like on the right track.  Related.

Then I got it.  Take the Modulus of the Coterminal Angle and 360.  Add 360 to that.  Then take the Module of 360 with it again.

Poof.  *Normalized Coterminal Angles.*

One shot.  Short expression.  No costly, CPU-intensive recursive looping or logical operations.  GPU-friendly.

Here is a complete proof you can use to test and verify yourself.  You can get same results algorithmically, only it's a lot more work for both humans and computers!  This is great for say, requestAnimationFrame.

```
console.clear();  //  Start with nice clean terminal to view our results.


//Normalize any angle
var normee = (angle)=>{  return(   (  (angle % 360)  +  360  )   %   360   );  }




// PROOF: Convert Coterminal Angles to Normal Angles (0 to 359)
// Start at -limit.  Convert angle each iteration.  Increment angle by degrees.   Stop at limit.

testNormalizedAngles = (limit,increment) => {
  var coterminalAngle = -limit;  var result = '';

  while( coterminalAngle <= limit){
    result += `MOFO ANGLE ${  coterminalAngle  } degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE ${  normee( coterminalAngle )  }\n`;
    coterminalAngle += increment;
  }

  return result;
}

//console.log(  testNormalizedAngles( 360*10, 15 )  );   // A BIT EXTREME, BUT REVEALING.

console.log(  testNormalizedAngles( 360*3, 45 )  );  // EASIER TO DECIPHER, BUT NOT AS THOROUGH.
```

Here is a concise, easy to understand sample proof using above function.

As you can see, the expression easily simplifies even the negative coterminal angles (those the real beasties!) in one quick, cheap shot.

```
> console.log(  testNormalizedAngles( 555, 45 )  );
MOFO ANGLE -555 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 165
MOFO ANGLE -510 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 210
MOFO ANGLE -465 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 255
MOFO ANGLE -420 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 300
MOFO ANGLE -375 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 345
MOFO ANGLE -330 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 30
MOFO ANGLE -285 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 75
MOFO ANGLE -240 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 120
MOFO ANGLE -195 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 165
MOFO ANGLE -150 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 210
MOFO ANGLE -105 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 255
MOFO ANGLE -60 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 300
MOFO ANGLE -15 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 345
MOFO ANGLE 30 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 30
MOFO ANGLE 75 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 75
MOFO ANGLE 120 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 120
MOFO ANGLE 165 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 165
MOFO ANGLE 210 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 210
MOFO ANGLE 255 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 255
MOFO ANGLE 300 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 300
MOFO ANGLE 345 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 345
MOFO ANGLE 390 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 30
MOFO ANGLE 435 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 75
MOFO ANGLE 480 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 120
MOFO ANGLE 525 degrees is COTERMINAL to NORM ANGLE 165
```

Well, hope y'all find this useful.  I did.

If so, please send a holler!  Would love to hear your war stories!

Answer (score -1):

Add any multiple of 360 degrees between which your possible input values could be (to take it above zero), and just take the remaining with %, like this

```
angle = 382;
normalized_angle = (angle+3600) %360;
//result = 22
```

The case above can take input angles down to -3600. You can add any number (multiple of 360) crazily high that would make the input value positive first.

Usually during an animation, your previous frame/step value would probably be already normalized by the previous step, so you'll be good to go by just adding 360:

```
normalized_angle = (angle+360) %360;
```

Answer (score -4):

Function that comes handy when normalizing angles (degrees) into interval [0, 360> :

```
float normalize_angle(float angle)
{
    float k = angle;

    while(k < 0.0)
        k += 360.0;
    while(k >= 360.0)
        k -= 360.0;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Nah, not so useful. If you enter (by accident) a very large value in this function it will hang in the loop.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the method in the question.